# Use multiple datepickers in same component Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I'm having the following problem:
I want to show two differents [datepickers](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) in the same component, but allowing to pick only year in one, and year and month in the other.
I've tryed using multiple providers as following:

```
export const MY_FORMATS_MONTH = {


parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

export const MY_FORMATS_YEAR = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: /.../
  templateUrl: /.../
  styleUrls: /.../
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: {MY_FORMATS_MONTH, MY_FORMATS_YEAR}, multi: true},
  ],
})
```

And them doing this to allow the user only select the things I mentioned before:

```
export class #MyClass implements OnInit {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
  year = new FormControl(moment());

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normalizedMonth: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.date.value;
    ctrlValue.month(normalizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }

  chosenOnlyYearHandler(normalizedYear: Moment, datepicker: MatDatepicker<Moment>) {
    const ctrlValue = this.year.value;
    ctrlValue.year(normalizedYear.year());
    this.year.setValue(ctrlValue);
    datepicker.close();
  }
```

And finally my html is this:

```
<!-- Year  -->
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="form-field col-sm-4">
        <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dpy" [formControl]="year">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dpy"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dpy
                        startView="multi-year"
                        (yearSelected)="chosenOnlyYearHandler($event, dpy)"
                        panelClass="example-year-picker">
        </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>          
    </div>

<!-- Month & Year  -->
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="form-field col-sm-4">
        <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #dp
                        startView="multi-year"
                        (yearSelected)="chosenYearHandler($event)"
                        (monthSelected)="chosenMonthHandler($event, dp)"
                        panelClass="example-month-picker">
        </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

If you have any advice about how to correctly implement multiple providers or how to indicate each input the dateFormat that corresponds, or just a better way of doing this I'll apreciate it if you help me.

Comment: Santi did you got any solution? I've same scenario and got stuck. please let me know if you got any solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60038450/11218448

> This feature is not fully implemented yet. You can see that here:
>
> https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4853
>
> For now you can try this:
>
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mulitdate-picker-demo